# VAST/VPAID tags player

Tags: vast

I'm looking for players with VAST/VPAID tags support. I know about JW Player and Kaltura player. Kaltura really expensive, JW is better option for me, 300USD per 2mill, but Im wondering if there is any other solution?

If I would have to be honest, I want the player mainly for Video Ads, content played after the ad will be 10secs random video, so I don't care about controlls support etc. All I need is player with support of VAST/VPAID tags and autoplay. Auto mute also would be nice feature, but it's not required (flash mainly).

Anyone? Thanks guys!

Comment: Kaltura supports it and it's open source

Answer (score 2):

For HTML5 you can use [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) with any of these two plugins:

- http://theonion.github.io/videojs-vast-plugin/
- https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima